# Visual Studio 2013 could not load file or assembly Microsoft.SqlServer.Managment.Sdk.Sfc Version 11.0.0.0

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to set up a dataconnection with SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3. My OS is Windows 8 x64 and i'm using Visual Studio 2013 (Express).  The error message look like this:

[image]

Ofcourse I searched for a solution for this error. Thing's I have tried: update from SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 to SP3. And I found out that installing these two files can solve the error:

\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi and x64\SQLSysClrTypes.msi

So I installed these two files for SQL Server 2008 , but it gives the same error. How can I fix this error?

**EDIT**: I fixed my problem by installing the SQL Server 2012 CLR Types file and the SQL Server 2012 Shared Managements Object file.

Comment: 11.0 is SQL Server 2012 https://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185

Comment: Didn't found that while I was searching on this error, but finally I managed to setup the connection.